# Groups and Users has many oder has many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

My app has User. These users belong to one or many groups. Obviously groups can have many users.

How do I do this in Rails? 
Is this a has many or a has many through association? What is the name of the third model if it's "has many through"? Nothing seems to make sense. Or is it just something like "group-user-link"?

If I have user_id and group_id in the respective tables, what happends when a User has multiple groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way. If you wanted to have many to many relationship you just need a joining table. Say, your user migh belongs to many groups and and groups may belongs to many users.

So you can define a joining table like this:

```
rails g model user_group user_id:integer:index group_id:integer:index
```

This will generate a migration file for you and a model user_group.rb

run the migration and put the following things on the other models:

in user_group.rb

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

In your user model

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :user_groups
     has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
    ....
    end
```

so in your group model

```
 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :user_groups
     has_many :users, through: :user_groups
    .....
    end
```

And this is how you can achieve your desired relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I think I also found a catchy modelname: User has Groups through Membership.